# Are there any solutions for removing access to Element.querySelector and other dom accessing methods?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am searching for solution to prevent accessing the dom outside parent element o fscoped javascript code.

Is there any solution to hook on all dom accessing methods, like we can hook on console methods for example or to change document root element depending on the scope.

It should be easy as var document = element and prevent access to global one, but document is immutable.

Any solutions?

Comment: Could this be a use-case for a closed shadow-root? Methods exist already for preventing access to (certain) elements in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use global constant.

```
const DOM = document.getElementById('main');
...
DOM.getElementsByTagName('div');
```

You could also override all methods on document object (getElementById, getElementsByTagName). In that case, be sure to call super:

```js
class myDocument extends Document{
    getDocumentById(value) {
      console.log(`Searching for ${value} inside 'main'. `)
      // If you want to remove access to theese functions simply comment out following line
      super.getDocumentById('main').getDocumentById(value)}    
}

var array = new newArray

array.push('new Value')
```

Where you replace 'main' with id of your component.

Comment: But how that disables access to document?

Comment: You override Document object with function that call selectors function on some other function which finds your main DOM.. i will edit post with example

Comment: But you cant override Document object, it is immutable. Everyone can access to window.document global.